# Find $\sum\frac{a(n)}{n(n+1)}$, where $a(n)$ --- number of 1's in binary expansion of n.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, summation

Let $a(n)$ is a [number of 1's in binary expansion of n](http://oeis.org/A000120),
find the sum
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a(n)}{n(n+1)}.
$$

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$

Comment: duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/432250/59379

Comment: @achillehui: well, at least our answers match. It's an interesting question, nonetheless. It's odd that I forgot the earlier question since I had upvoted your answer (and even commented on it). I'm getting too old.

Comment: @robjohn, it is not a surprise you forget. If this isn't one of my highest voted answer, I will not be able to locate it so quickly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can uniquely write the integers with bit $n$ set as $(2k+1)2^n+j$ where $0\le j\lt2^n$. Thus, the contribution to the sum from integers with bit $n$ set is
$$
\begin{align}
\hspace{-5mm}\sum_{\text{$i$ with bit $n$ set}}\left(\frac1i-\frac1{i+1}\right)
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^{2^n-1}\left[\frac1{(2k+1)2^n+j}-\frac1{(2k+1)2^n+j+1}\right]\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left[\frac1{(2k+1)2^n}-\frac1{(2k+2)2^n}\right]\\[9pt]
&=\log(2)\,2^{-n}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
If we now sum over all the bits, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a(n)}{n(n+1)}
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\log(2)\,2^{-n}\\
&=2\log(2)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: +1 for an upvote you could have recieved  11 months ago.